# I2C Communication with sensor CCS Compiler

Tags: c, pic, i2c

I need to communicate with a sensor via I2C. The sensor's datasheet https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/ssd/s11059-02dt_etc_kpic1082e.pdf   shows an example of a communication:

[I2C example of datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzlrr.jpg)

And my code:

```
#include <18f2550.h>
#fuses   HSPLL,NOWDT,NOPROTECT,NOLVP,NODEBUG,USBDIV,PLL5,CPUDIV1,VREGEN
#USE     delay(clock=48000000)
#use i2c(Master,Fast,sda=PIN_B0,scl=PIN_B1)

#include <usb_cdc.h>
void main() {
    i2c_start();
    i2c_write(0x54);
    i2c_write(0x00);
    i2c_write(0x89);
    i2c_write(0x54);
    i2c_write(0x00);
    i2c_write(0x09);
    i2c_stop();

    usb_cdc_init();
    usb_init();
    while(TRUE) {
        delay_ms(10);
        i2c_write(0x54);
        i2c_write(0x03);
        i2c_write(0x55);

        int8 RM = i2c_read(1);
        int8 RL = i2c_read(1);
        int8 GM = i2c_read(1);
        int8 GL = i2c_read(1);
        int8 BM = i2c_read(1);
        int8 BL = i2c_read(1);
        int8 IM = i2c_read(1);
        int8 IL = i2c_read(0);
        i2c_stop();

        usb_task();
        if (usb_enumerated()) {
            printf( usb_cdc_putc,"%d", (RM << 8) | RL );                        
            printf(usb_cdc_putc, "\f ");
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if my code is allright.

Comment: First thing to check - does it compile? Does it run? Does it do what you want it to do?

Comment: Sorry - I am not able (willing ;))  to read the complete spec. 
Typically a sensor will have a register to query if the conversion / calculation is ready . Can't see that.  
Also seems like i2c_stop() - comes before i2c_start() in your loop?

Comment: Eugene Sh. It compiles and it runs but i'm not sure if the data is allright. The data varies but with the same numbers all the time and doest not seem to varies with light (sensor works that way).

michael - mlc. Yeah, I'm not restarting the communication with Start condition or restart condition. I will modify that part.

Comment: Query the device part number and verify if this is correct

Comment: It looks to me like you're missing some parts of the sequence.  According to the spec, to read data, you must follow: [Start->Address(W)->Register->Restart->Address(R)->DataBytes->Stop]
Inside the while loop, all I see is: [Address(W)->Register->Address(R)->DataBytes->Stop]
You must have a start condition for each transmission sequence and you must have the restart condition between writing and reading.

Answer (score 0):

in the posted code, the sequencing of I/O between the microprocessor and the device is not correct

The following link is for a different sensor, but does show the correct  [I2C sequence](https://robot-electronics.co.uk/i2c-tutorial)

You will need to adjust:

1. the bus address,
2. the register address,
3. the command,
4. and the number of data bytes

for the chip your using: S11059-02DT/-03DS

Strongly suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give the fixed values meaningful names to make a reader of your code (including your self at some future date) an easy time understanding what the code is doing